# Feature classes not visible to some ArcSDE users?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

Some of my organization's data (several SDE databases) has been migrated to a new server and we have recently upgraded from ArcGIS 10.2 for Server to ArcGIS 10.4 for Server and SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2014. Users are using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 or 10.2.

Now when some users attempt to view the migrated data, no feature classes are shown. Feature datasets *are* shown however. For others, the feature classes are present and may be worked with as usual. Any ideas of why this is happening and what may be done to allow all users to see these feature classes?

Feature classes have been absent for some users using Desktop versions 10.1 and 10.2. So I do not think it is a Desktop version issue. I do not think it is a Native Client version issue because I believe users would be prevented from viewing the database entirely.

Comment: Has the data been loaded into the SDE databases using different user accounts? This sounds like a permissions issue - make sure that the various data owners have granted permissions to all applicable users. It's possible that these permissions didn't carry over during the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks @Radar. A permissions issue does sound likely. IT resolved the issue and I do not (and probably will never) know what they did. So, unfortunately, this question will have to remain a little open-ended without me providing a conclusion.